# How to get the HREF value of an element using CasperJS and XPath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying to find the best way to target the PDF download link and download it to the correct directory on my computer.  I'm trying to use CasperJS & XPath, as it seems like its the easiest way.

Currently what I have:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var fs = require('fs');
casper.start('http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=APHIS-2012-0047-0291');

var classVal = x("//a[@class='gwt-Anchor']/@href");
casper.download(classVal, 'C:/users/bnickerson/desktop/script/result/p.pdf');
```

Whenever this runs, it downloads a file, but its an html file just named p.pdf.  If I open it, I get this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /%5Bobject%20Object%5D
type Status report
message /%5Bobject%20Object%5D
description The requested resource (/%5Bobject%20Object%5D) is not available.
JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final
```

The page that I'm trying to get this PDF download from:
http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=APHIS-2012-0047-0291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look closer what arguments <kbd>[`download`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download)</kbd> accepts. Don't mix selectors and plain strings. `classVal` is an XPath selector and **not** the textual content that is behind the selector. You can retrieve an element attribute using <kbd>[`getElementAttribute`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementattribute)</kbd>.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var classVal = x("//a[@class='gwt-Anchor' and contains(@href,'contentType=pdf')]");
    var url = casper.getElementAttribute(classVal, "href");
    casper.download(url, 'C:/users/bnickerson/desktop/script/result/p.pdf');
});
```

Comment: I used your code, and it still gives me the error. Could it be something to do with the actual href itself isn't a direct link to the pdf, its some sort of stream? http://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?objectId=09000064811113cc&disposition=attachment&contentType=pdf

Comment: @Prokzy Your selector was not specific enough.